# explicitly setting the a4paper option has no effect using scrreprt?

Tags: koma-script, paper-size, optional-arguments

I compile the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

with `pdflatex`. If I leave out the `a4paper` option and compile again, the produced pdf will be exactly the same in terms of layout. Additionally, both times the log file states the following:

```
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 10
(typearea)             BCOR = 0.0pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 418.25555pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = -6%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 17.3562pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = 17.3562pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 595.80026pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = -25.16531pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 17.0pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 20.40001pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 11.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 47.60002pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 13.6pt
```

The conclusion I draw from this is that the `a4paper` option is the default in `scrreprt` and therefore it is generally not necessary to  use this option when dealing with this class. Is this conclusion valid, and if so then why do a lot of people still use this option although it seems to be redundant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the English KOMA manual:

> The option `a4paper` could be omitted with `scrreprt`, since this is a
>   predefined setting for all KOMA-Script classes.

I suppose including it is just an old habit or something.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I could not locate this passage myself. Maybe I acted a bit too hasty.

Answer (score 1):

Including `a4paper` makes the switching to another `documentclass` that does not have `a4paper` as the default easier. It also makes it easier for other people that use a given Latex code as a reference to see where and how the paper size would be changed.